# Android studio debug does actions that simple run doesn't

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an app using `firebase realtime database`. the app has a value `eventlistener` for reading data that should run at the first run of the activity and whenever the database's data change. This is my code:

```
    this.mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = this.mDatabase.getReference();
    DatabaseReference userIntRef = databaseReference.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("Page Number");
    userIntRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            currentPage = dataSnapshot.getValue(long.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.i("Database Error", databaseError.toException().toString());
        }
    });
```

For some reason, when I simply run the app, this block of code doesn't run when the activity is created, but when I debug the code, it runs as it should.
Does anyone know why, or how to solve it?

Comment: Which block of code exactly? And why do you think it does not run?

Comment: There are some blocks of code that run only when DEBUG mode is TRUE this doesn't seem to be the case...

Comment: I understood the issue, when i was in debug mode the program had time to do something in a back thread that was necessary for the activity. I added slight suspension and it worked just fine

Comment: You should answer your own question instead of placing this comment. Otherwise it will likely be closed as the question has been solved.